# Consume WSDL with client certificate in C #

Tags: c#, ssl, soap, wsdl, client-certificates

I created an CA, a certificate, and installed on the server (IIS-8), demanded client certificate, authorized the new CA, I created a WSDL service test and published on the server.

When I use a browser to access the same link it requests the certificate (the certificate is installed on the machine) I select it and everything works fine.

I used a SOAP tester and it works well, runs the method successfully. (Boomerang extension for Chrome).

I'm in Visual Studio 2015 in a Windows test form design, to try to consume the service Add Web Reference, it appears on the left full WSDL, however have the "Forbidden" on the right side and can not include the reference.

I visited some topics, some helped me a little, but still could not solve this case.

Evidence:

[image: Error]

[image: wsdl]

Comment: did you ever figure out the answer to this question? I am running into this same issue right now